# TensorFlow GPU could not load cuda libraries on PyCharm

Tags: nvidia, cuda, pycharm, tensorflow

I'm having a hard time trying to get the things work with TensorFlow, nvidia and PyCharm. Basically, I had followed the pre/post steps during [installation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions) process and ended up with:

```
eric@xps:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

eric@xps:~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:08:53_PST_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
eric@xps:~$ nvidia-smi
Sun Jul 11 15:01:09 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.31       Driver Version: 465.31       CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    374MiB /  2004MiB |      8%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1582      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                158MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1932      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               62MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3612      G   ...cef_18.log --shared-files        1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3666      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          146MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, whenever I try to run from PyCharm:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

I got this error:

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Whatsoever, If I do start a python console and do the same the result obtained is:

```
eric@xps:~$ python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 11 2021, 08:20:37) 
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2021-07-11 15:06:36.919852: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
>>> print(tf.__version__)
2.5.0
>>>
```

So, I'm wondering what could else should I configure to have it work properly.
I've added cuda to PATH:

```
eric@xps:~$ echo $PATH
/home/eric/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/cuda/bin
```

I've setup the Python Interpreter as the one detected by PyCharm which is /usr/bin/python

But still not success in such a simple task. Any tip/help will be highly appreciated :)

Also looked at:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/path-ld-library-path/48080

Additional info:

```
eric@xps:~$ lspci |grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
```

```
PyCharm 2021.1.3 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-211.7628.24, built on June 30, 2021
Licensed to Eric Rodriguez
Subscription is active until January 18, 2022.
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1341.60 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.11.0-7620-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8

Current Desktop: pop:GNOME


eric@xps:~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: xps
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
  Operating System: Pop!_OS 21.04
            Kernel: Linux 5.11.0-7620-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```